# How to force timepicker and datepicker look same on every device?

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

When I debug using AVD Galaxy Nesus API 21 the timepicker look this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5YCe.png

but when I debug using oracle virtual box with google android 4.3 it look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nfGp.png

Is there any to force timepicker look same on every device (prefer analog type)? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to stick to one constant theme for your app

Comment: I'm using 1 theme only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any to force timepicker look same on every device (prefer analog type)?

Stop using the built-in widgets and either find one from a library that you like or write one yourself. Google changes the look of these widgets from time to time, in ways that transcend simple theme changes, and there is nothing that you can really do about that.